# How to Count the Number of Values that meet certain conditions in a df in R

Tags: r

Let's say that I have data like the following

```
date  value location
1/1    10      A    
1/2    15      A
1/3    20      A
2/1    15      A
2/2    10      A
2/3    5       A
2/4    12      B
2/5    15      B
2/6    5       B
2/7    20      A
```

I would like the count of all values over 10 after 1/31 aggregated by location. So my output would give me 3 for location A and 2 for location B.
Any ideas how this could be implemented in R?

Comment: `table(subset(transform(dat,date=strptime(date,"%m/%d")),date>as.Date("2018-01-31")&value>=10)$location)`

Answer (score 2):

Once you standardized your date field (assuming the year is 2018) you could use the `dplyr` package to filter your dataset to the conditions you need and group by the location and tally.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0(df$date, '/', format(Sys.Date(), '%Y')),
                        format = '%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
  filter(date > as.Date('2018-01-31')) %>%
  filter(value >= 10) %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  tally()
```

Comment: So I actually posted an oversimplified version of my problem. I am actually not comparing to a static value, but a value that is unique to each site. Is there a way to adjust the "filter(value" line to accommodate  this?

Comment: I would need more context, but it sounds like you'd like to develop a loop or a function that uses a specific value from each site. if that can be derived programmatically then you can store that specific value into an object, i.e `site_val`. The `filter` function can take objects... `filter(value >= site_val)`. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

using base R you can do:

```
newdat=subset(transform(dat,date=strptime(date,"%m/%d")),date>as.Date("2018-01-31")&value>=10)
table(newdat$location)
A B 
3 2
```

or

```
  aggregate(value~location,newdat,length)
  location value
1        A     3
2        B     2
```

Taking into consideration the comment by `thelaemail`you can do:

```
aggregate(value~location,dat,length,subset = strptime(date,"%m/%d")>as.Date("2018-01-31")&value>=10)
  location value
1        A     3
2        B     2
```

Comment: As an aside, `aggregate` takes a `subset=` argument so you could do it in a single step using `subset=format(as.Date(date, format="%m/%d"), "%m/%d") > "01/31" & value >= 10` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit of `lubridate` functionality to D.sen's answer:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

thresh <- 10
date_thresh <- "2018-01-31"

df %>%
  mutate(date = mdy(paste0(date, "/2018"))) %>%
  filter(date > date_thresh, value > thresh) %>%
  group_by(location) %>%
  tally()

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  location     n
  <fct>    <int>
1 A            2
2 B            2
```